# Is “Pandemics are ended” grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, passive-voice

In this sentence:

> Pandemics are ended.

I got passive misuse error in online grammar checkers, but I don't know why? Anybody can help me why this sentence is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know why your online grammar checker calls this a "passive misuse error". Your exact text isn't at all idiomatic to my ear, but that's because of the combination of plural ***pandemics***, the auxiliary ***are***, and the past tense ***ended***. You'd be fine with ***The pandemic is over*** or ***The pandemic has finished***, for example.

Comment: The **The pandemic's ended** the apostrophe 's stands for "has"

Comment: The complete sentence is: *In this programme, we’ll be finding out how pandemics are ended.* @Mari-LouA

Comment: Then you should have said so from the beginning. Your example is a sentence, it starts with a capital letter and ends with a full stop (period). Why would you exclude the main clause?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm sorry I thought the first part had no effect in my question, same warning is given in both cases by online grammar checkers

Comment: Well, the complete sentence makes sense  but I would avoid the passive voice in any case and say **how pandemics end** because the verb "end" doesn't usually take an object, e.g. He didn't know where to begin or end. When the road ends, you'll come to a T-junction.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A One could write it that way, but I might not.  "I am going to discuss how pandemics are ended" suggests to me a discussion of active, intentional steps are taken to halt a pandemic, while "I am going to discuss how pandemics end" suggests a focus on natural processes that terminate pandemics. So I find the meaning subtly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no explicit subject specified, a grammar checker might flag this as a passive construction. Some people believe that use of the passive is often poor writing, and that many writers overuse the passive.  Therefore, grammar checkers often raise a warning when they detect something that they categorize as a passive construction.

The passive voice is a perfectly valid construction, grammatically. In some cases it can be used to obscure who or what took an action. For example if one writes "*Mistakes were made.*" that obscures who made them. This can be used to hide responsibility, and to engage in dishonest writing. Because of such writing, use of the passive has gained a bad reputation. But there are good reasons to use the passive voice. For example, if the author wants to focus on the result, not the person who caused it.  One might write "*Prices went up.*" If the author wants to focus on what happened to the prices, and not the complex economic causes, this might be the best way to write about it.

In any case, I would not class "*Pandemics are ended.*" as a use of the passive, because "are" is a stative verb, not an action verb.

All of this shows that grammar checker apps have at best limited value, and cannot be relied on to distinguish good grammar from bad. At best such an app reminds an author to reconsider a phrase or sentence, and think if it is good in context.

Comment: I agree with your penultimate paragraph - OP's text doesn't look much like a "passive" construction to me. I think maybe it's just blind chance that some bit of software rejected it (it seems *syntactically fine* - just hopelessly non-idiomatic). And as @Mari-Lou A
 comments, ***The** pandemic **has** ended* is beyond reproach.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can imagine a text discussing multiple pandemics at once. in whch "*Pandemics are ended.*" might be appropriate. Now it seems that this was but a fragment of "*In this programme, we’ll be finding out how pandemics are ended.*" I do not consider that a flawed sentence, i find it quite natural. I never said that OP's construction was passive, I said a grammar checker might label it as such.

Comment: Sure - there's nothing unusual about *Let's look at how **wars are ended***. But that's never gonna convince me that ***Wars are ended*** could ever be an idiomatic assertion in English, no matter what the context.

Answer (score 2):

> Pandemics are ended.

The sentence above is not passive. To make the sentence into a passive a transitive verb with the auxiliary verb "be" is necessary. I would suggest using the **passive present perfect** voice because no time reference is given and the emphasis is felt in the present.

> The pandemic [subject] ***has been*** *beaten* / *wiped out*/ *defeated* (by XYZ).

You could also say “The pandemic **has been put to an end.**”

Another way of making the original sentence grammatical would be to use the Present Perfect tense

> The pandemic’**s ended**

The apostrophe **'s** stands for "has" as in “The pandemic HAS ended.” (If only that were true.)

Comment: I'm sure I haven't looked at your ELL profile for many years, but for some reason I did so just now, and was surprised to see that stroppy suspension note from last year. But given such officious moderation, it's no longer a surprise to me that less and less people seem to be using the SO English sites (which I've long thought can't *all* be down to the sometime "new" owners' lamentable treatment of Monica! :)